# split up (with specified delimiter) a selected column

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a tab-delimited file and want to modify it. The last column is pipe-delimited and I'd like to split that column up (from pipe to tab) while avoiding splitting up other columns with pipes.

This works to convert pipe to tab but I'm unable to have it do the splitting only on a selected column 13. Is there a way to have this work just on the last column without having to specify it?

```
awk -F'|' '$13=$13' OFS="\t" inputfile.tsv > split.tsv
```

Comment: You should add sample input with expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider this tab-delimited test file:

```
$ cat file
a|b     c|d     e|f     g
one     two     three   four
```

To break up the third column on `|`:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{gsub(/[|]/, "\t", $3)} 1' OFS='\t' file
a|b     c|d     e       f       g
one     two     three   four
```

For your file, you will want to replace `$3` with `$13`.

```
awk -F'\t' '{gsub(/[|]/, "\t", $13)} 1' OFS='\t' file
```

Or, to replace the last column, whatever column it is, use:

```
awk -F'\t' '{gsub(/[|]/, "\t", $NF)} 1' OFS='\t' file
```

#### How it works

- `-F'\t'` sets the field separator on input to a tab.
- `gsub(/[|]/, "\t", $13)` replaces `|` with a tab in field `$13`.
- `1` is awk's cryptic short-hand for print-the-line.
- `OFS='\t'` tells awk to use a tab as the field separator on output.

#### Alternate form

It may be clearer and easier to maintain if `\t` is coded just once instead of three times.  In that case (hat tip: [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub(/[|]/, OFS, $NF)} 1' file
```

Comment: `n=` probably unnecessary.  `\|` notation is one char less.  Also perhaps `$NF` to identify last field.  Also use `OFS` in `gsub` for consistency.

Comment: @karakfa Thank you.  Answer updated to remove the superfluous `n=` and offer the `$NF` option.  (I am in the habit of using `[|]`, even at the cost of an additional character, because the same form works under POSIX ("basic") regex as well.  Others, of course, may have good reasons for other habits.)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I couldn't get past the 'split' function and now see the gsub function is really the missing element.